# Copy normal field values in elasticsearch mapping as nested

Tags: elasticsearch

My index contains a nested document "multi_location" in the below format. I need to query "mapsResponseDisplay" field in each nested object.

```
{
    "multi_location": [
        {
            "country": "Canada",
            "city": "Lachine",
            "mapsResponseDisplay": false
        },
        {
            "mapsResponseDisplay": true,
            "country": "Canada",
            "city": "Markham"
        }
    ]
}
```

but the field "multi_location" mapping type is not a nested one. Due to other API dependencies, I cannot change the field mapping type to a nested one. Is there anyway where I can copy the "multi_location" value with other field name at the time of indexing with nested mapping type? I have tried "copy_to" functionality, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try querying with multi_location.mapsResponseDisplay in your fields attribute of your query ? It should work directly without adding any nested support.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with multi_location.mapsResponseDisplay. But it is not giving correct results. If mapping type is not nested it is not querying each object inside the array.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the problem you are facing with copy_to ? Is it a problem with a copy not allowed from non-nested to nested field ?

Comment: When I use copy_to, the structure is not being copied as nested from non-nested field. Below is my mapping

`
"multi_location": {
 "properties": {}  
}`

If I give the mapping in the below way

`"multi_location": {
 "properties": {}  ,
  copy_to:["some other field"]
}
`

It is throwing mapping error. Due to which i have to give copy_to for individual fields. So the nested structure is not being retained when I use copy_to for individual fields.

Comment: @ShaileshPratapwar is it possible to copy "multi_location" values to another field name like "multi_location_map" with nested type mapping at the time of indexing ?